# How do i make a picturebox selectable?

Tags: winforms, user-interface

I am making a very basic map editor. I'm halfway through it and one problem i hit is how to delete an object.

I would like to press delete but there appears to be no keydown event for pictureboxes and it will seem like i will have it only on my listbox.

What is the best solution for deleting an object in my editor?

Comment: in witch language, want you do it?

Comment: @were: I think you can assume C# or VB.NET. The former seems to be more common. Translating the *code* itself should be the least of the problems, though.

Comment: C# and i can read vb just fine. Maybe i'll consider dragging the object offscreen a delete solution. To bad i didnt think of it right away.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll want the PictureBox to participate in the tabbing order and show that it has the focus.  That takes a bit of minor surgery.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form.  Implement the KeyDown event.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class SelectablePictureBox : PictureBox {
  public SelectablePictureBox() {
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);
    this.TabStop = true;
  }
  protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
    this.Focus();
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
  }
  protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e) {
    this.Invalidate();
    base.OnEnter(e);
  }
  protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e) {
    this.Invalidate();
    base.OnLeave(e);
  }
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe) {
    base.OnPaint(pe);
    if (this.Focused) {
      var rc = this.ClientRectangle;
      rc.Inflate(-2, -2);
      ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(pe.Graphics, rc);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Hans Passant- does it really participate in the tabbing order on a windows form? Because, it doesn't receive focus when TAB is pressed from the previous control or CTRL+TAB is pressed from the next control. What's your conception on it? Regards.

Comment: Yes, that was the point of this code.  I just checked it again, tabs like a mother.  Don't forget to actually *replace* the picture box with this new control.

Comment: @Hans Passant- tell me what am I missing. I created the SelectablePictureBox, made it a part of a class library, referenced the class library to my TestBed; where I added a form containing a button and the SelectablePictureBox only. Our control only receives focus when the mouse is clicked on it. When the focus is on the control and TAB is pressed, the focus sets on the button but never comes back to our control when subsequent TABs are pressed.

Comment: @Hans Passant- My mistake! Forgot to delete the default overloaded constructor for the container in the SelectablePictureBox class. Sorry to make you go all throughout your code once again for no reason.

Comment: @Hans Passant- However, I just want to make sure that the SelectablePictureBox doesn't provide us with the KeyDown event by default. So we have to write the event handler method in the form that is hosting the SelectablePictureBox control and add it to the control's KeyDown event in the form's constructor or load event explicitly. Tell me if I am wrong. Your post has been of great help. A lot of people long for the selectable behavior of the PictureBox. I will definitely refer this link to them.

Comment: +1 from me. I just want to know one more thing, How to make multiple picturebox selectable? For eg, if user select pictureboxs with holding Ctrl key and clicking left button of mouse,multiple picturebox should be selectable.

Comment: Awesome idea as always from @Hans Passant, this helped me a lot, but to be a perfect solution I added a custom update to shadow to expose the `TabIndex` and `TabStop` properties to make them browseable, otherwise they are still inaccesible from the **View -> Tab Order** feature of visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is the best methode:

http://felix.pastebin.com/Q0YbMt22

Comment: i see where your going with that.

Comment: You can use the same effect in a delegate method into the PictureBox's Click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

... 8 years after ...

An alternative to Hans Passant's code, which doesn't require you to create a new class just so your `PictureBox` is in the tab order, is to set `TabStop` to `true`, and call `SetStyle()` directly on the `PictureBox`, optimally after `InitializeComponent()` is called.

`TabStop` is public, so it's easily set, but `SetStyle()` is protected, so reflection comes to the rescue!

```
myPictureBox.TabStop = true;
typeof(PictureBox)
    .GetMethod("SetStyle", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Invoke(myPictureBox, new object[] { ControlStyles.Selectable, true });
```

This of course, doesn't do anything like getting the focus when the `PictureBox` is clicked, so you have to do that in its various events as you see fit.