# Problems with keys on winform and focus

Tags: winforms

My winform window was working fine then i added a combobox to it. Now my code which uses theform_KeyDown does not work. From my understanding when it gets focus it gives it to my combobox thus my window keydown event never happens? I had pictureboxes and no matter where i clicked i was able to use the keys nicely.

How do i allow keys to work again painlessly? it seems like i need to modify all the forms setfocus or add key events for this to work again. What is the easiest way?

I asked a [focus question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743174/how-do-i-make-a-picturebox-selectable/2744485#2744485) so the answer may help give ideas but probably not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a form contains a child control that can receive the focus (in other words, not a picture box) then the form can no longer receive the focus.  And thus won't get keyboard messages anymore, they'll go to the control with the focus.  A quick fix is to set the form's KeyPreview property to True.