# Make a textbox not blink?

Tags: winforms

I am trying to get a control i can click on, press any keys (except tab) and have it take in the input. [I tried using this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743174/how-do-i-make-a-picturebox-selectable/2744485#2744485) and had a problem with the arrow keys changing the focus. [That question is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397684/make-a-piturebox-not-lose-focus-on-arrow-keys)

The textbox seems to work but i dont like how it blinks. As in the line that shows where you next letter will be placed. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Blinking is a system wide option. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971316.aspx) out.

Comment: Don't use global state to manage a local problem -- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you create a UserControl based on the standard textbox you can use [Control::IsInputKey][1] to override default behaviour which causes the control to lose focus.

Comment: i'm confused, how does this help? i only lose focus on the picturebox i make a user control of. The textbox has the blink problem only.