# C# picturebox loses focus

Tags: c#, events, focus

I am working on an application that uses a PictureBox to display an image.  When the picturebox has the focus I have implemented several shortcut keys to manipulate the image; scrolling, rotating, zooming, etc.  The problem is, there is no indication to the user that the image HAS the focus.  Looking over the properties of the PictureBox I cannot see any event linked to losing the focus.

I can check the keydown event to GIVE the focus to the box, and then change the border or background or whatever to indicate that the PictureBox has focus, but I cannot find a way to tell when the focus LEAVES the PictureBox.  The only focus related Events seem to be "Validating" and Validated".

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Because it doesn't get focus.  What is the PictureBox in?  That is likely what was really getting focus.

Comment: Hans Passant offers this as an alternative:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743174/how-do-i-make-a-picturebox-selectable