# How to draw rectangle with solid border?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing, border

I use an answer from [How do i make a picturebox selectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743174/how-do-i-make-a-picturebox-selectable) to make PictureBox selectable.

All works, but lines of border rectangle are dashed. How can I make it solid?

Comment: [A focus rectangle is a dotted rectangle that Windows uses to indicate what control has the current keyboard focus.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2czzc46(v=vs.110).aspx) Is there another type of method available with the word `Rectangle` in it? Because to me it seems like the `DrawFocusRectangle` is meant to only draw dotted rectangles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It it because

```
      ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(pe.Graphics, rc);
```

is drawing a dashed rectangle.

To draw a solid rectangle use:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
  base.OnPaint(pe);
  if (this.Focused)
  {
    var rc = this.ClientRectangle;
    rc.Inflate(-2, -2);
    pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc);
  }
}
```